# How to find a total order with constrained comparisons

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

There are $25$ horses with different speeds. My goal is to rank all of them, by using only runs with $5$ horses, and taking partial rankings. How many runs do I need, at minimum, to complete my task?

As a partial answer, I know that is possible to determine the first $3$ horses with $7$ runs, and, by a slight generalization of the optimal algorithm used to find the first three, have the complete ranking in $20$ runs.

Is it possible to do better?

What if we have $n$ horses and want to rank them with runs with $k$ horses?

Comment: You'll need at the very least $\log(25!)/\log(5!)\gt12$ runs.

Comment: Use stopwatch and then 5 runs are enough..

Comment: You seem to have a [transitive tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)#Transitivity) on 25 nodes, do not know the edge directions, and are sampling 5-vertex induced subgraphs until you find all the edge directions.  It might be that a "dynamic" scheme (where we can adjust our decisions based on knowledge of earlier partial rankings) might be better than a "static" scheme; is this allowed?

Comment: Yes, dynamic schemes are allowed, and, in fact, my solution in 20 runs is dynamic.

Comment: I have an update. If we start with 5 runs with all the 25 horses, and at least 2 of the first 4 horses run together in one of the 5 initial runs, we can find the first 5 horses with 8 runs only. This leads to an adaptive algorithm that gives the complete ranking in about 18.5 runs (average), 20 runs (worst).

Comment: Finding the top three horses was (will have been? it's a later question...) discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56159/number-of-races-needed

Comment: With $k=2$, this is problem is actually equivalent to a standard sorting algorithm. `quicksort` is I think the best one and runs in $n\log_2n$.

Comment: @Tom-Tom `quicksort` is not necessarily the best regarding the absolute count of (best/average/worst case) comparison operations. But as there are $n!$ possible orders and each comparison gives us at most one bit of info, we certainly need at least $\log_2 n!\approx\log_2( n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n})\sim n\log_2 n$

Comment: For $k=2$ and $n \leq 15$ the optimal number of "runs" is here: https://oeis.org/A036604

Comment: In the best case, you will only need 6 runs! Let $h_i$ be the i-th horse. Suppose the true speeds are $h_p < h_q \forall p<q$. In the first $k \leq 5$ runs, run horses $h_{5k-4}$ to $h_{5k}$. On the 6-th run, run $(h_5, h_{10}, h_{15}, h_{20}, h_{25})$, which will finish in that order. Now you have the full ordering. So I think this question needs to be asking the minimum number of runs required in the WORST case.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky: $v_1 < v_2 < v_3 < v_4 < v_5$ and $v_6 < v_7 < v_8 < v_9 < v_{10}$ together with $v_5 < v_{10}$ do not ensure $v_9 < v_5$ or the opposite, so $6$ runs are not enough to get a complete ranking.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio my friend pointed me to a strategy that does work in 6 runs, it is just very unlikely to happen. run 1: $h_1<h_2<h_3<h_4<h_5$, run 2: $h_5<h_6<h_7<h_8<h_9$, run 3: $h_9<h_{10}<h_{11}<h_{12}<h_{13}$, run 4: $h_{13}<h_{14}<h_{15}<h_{16}<h_{17}$, run 5: $h_{17}<h_{18}<h_{19}<h_{20}<h_{21}$, run 6: $h_{21}<h_{22}<h_{23}<h_{24}<h_{25}$.

Answer (score 5):

Just some lower and upper bounds.

There must be at least $13$ races, because you need $25!$ possible results, all the possible orderings of the $25$ horses - and there are only $120=5!$ results in each race. Since $120^{12}<25!<120^{13},$ you definitely cannot do it in $12$ races.

With $n$ horses and races of $k$ horse, you need at least:
$$\left\lceil \log_{k!}(n!)\right\rceil$$ races.

(When $k=2,$ this is the usual minimum of $\log_2(n!)\approx n\log_2 n-n$ comparisons to do a complete sorting of a list.

It can definitely be done in $30$ races, by considering all 30 lines in the finite affine plane $\left(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z\right)^2.$ That is definitely overkill - every horse is raced against every other horse.

Comment: Could you explain why it's $k!^x$ please? (where x is the number of races). I think I understand that each race/comparison produces k! results because that's the number of permutations possible for each comparison but why multiply consecutive results? When solving by logic, some races produced more information than others so I'm confused.

Comment: $k!$ is just the maximum amount of “information” you can get from an additional race. If two races share a pair of horses, then the second race provides less additional information. This is why these values are lower bounds. @tiktok

Comment: Specifically, after $m$ races of size $k,$ we get a total of **at most** $(k!)^m$ different results. But to determine all $n!$ ways of ordering $n$ horses, we need **at least $n!$** different results, so we need $(k!)^m\geq n!,$ or $m\geq\log_{k!}(n!).$